# Pretty simple constructor question that I just can't get. Java

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

- Create a class with a default constructor (one that takes no arguments) that prints a message. In your main() method, create an object of this class.
- Add an overloaded constructor to your code from step 1. The new constructor should take a String argument and print it along with your message. Modify main() so that it creates a second object of this class, using the new constructor.

So the second part is literally like written in another language to me I have absolutely no idea how to do that, and the first part here's what I got so far:

```
public class Constructors {
    System.out.println("Message");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

It's giving me an error when I'm just trying to print that message. I'm so confused, I'm not asking you to do my lab for me by any means but I'm so confused by this it's out of control.

Comment: Start by looking up what "overloaded constructor" means, then try implementing one that accepts a String argument.

Comment: "I'm so confused by this it's out of control." -- question is terrible, but the way you asked it is just to funny not to upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor shouldn't be the name of your class, the constructor is the method that creates an instance of your class (object)

So the first point means that you create an object without parameters that will print a message when you call it from the main method

```
public class WhateverClass{

    //this is the first constructor
    public WhateverClass(){

        System.out.prinln("A message");

    }

    //this is the main method
    public static void main (String[] args){
        new WhateverClass(); //will print the message
    }
}
```

Then you create another constructor that gonna overload the first one because it gonna have the same signature except it gonna takes a parameter. And then you call it from main method exactly as the first one. Here:

```
public class WhateverClass{

    //this is the first constructor
    public WhateverClass(){

        System.out.prinln("A message");

    }

    //this is the second constructor
    public WhateverClass(String message){

        System.out.prinln(message);

    }

    //this is the main method
    public static void main (String[] args){
        new WhateverClass(); //will print the message
        new WhateverClass("A message");
    }
}
```

And your exemple doesn't work because your print method is not in any method and cannot be executed from where it is.

You should really read books and articles about the basics of OO programmation.

Comment: Thanks for this this helped a lot. I understand kind of what I needed to do at the beginning and why it wasn't printing, but the instructions that we were given for the lab is what was really confusing me. Thanks for the help though I think I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

A method invocation should either be part of a method body or an initializer expression or block. Move that `println` invocation to an actual *constructor* (google that) and you should be good to go. You can go through the "[Starting Java](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/99132) (my sticky thread)" thread aimed to beginners (feel free to offer suggestions).

BTW, there is a difference between default and no-arg constructor. A default constructor is always a no-arg constructor and is automatically provided in case you don't but the reverse is not true.

Comment: "Starting Java" is nice. But you should give a disclaimer that it's your own posting.

Comment: @zengr: It's just a forum thread, not a blog post. I don't gain anything by linking to it. But added nonetheless.

Comment: though, the article "Similarities and Differences between Java and C++" is really old, more than 10yrs old.

Comment: @zengr: I don't think a lot has changed on either sides on a conceptual level (of course we exclude C++0x out of this discussion). Do you have another link which you think should go in there?

Comment: For example: "Java does not support enums but, as mentioned above, does support named constants.". Java has enums.  The wiki itself it pretty good. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: @zengr: Good suggestion; I've updated the post and added links to some video lectures which was pending from my side. :)